# Trigger textarea ctrl-z undo buffer update

Tags: javascript, jquery, buffer, undo-redo

I have a text area, it's rather large with quite a bit of data. I want the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> undo buffer to be updated more frequently, probably every time the user hits enter. By default as far as I can tell the buffer is updated only when the textarea on blur or on <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd>/<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>.

I don't want to blur the textarea every time they hit enter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you blur and set focus back-to-back so that the undo state is set more frequently?

Basically, listen for key press, and on the enter key, make the switch.  It may be glitchy in some cases, but I think it will work.  To catch characters typed quickly after the enter key, set focus on a small text input on a box behind your main box, and then when re-focusing, add any text that was missing.

Comment: Wow, that worked better than I thought. I just $(this).blur().focus() and it solved the problem... Right now I just have it doing that on all keyups so in IE it's slow, maybe I'll do a timeout for it. Thanks for the suggestion, it still seems a bit like a work around though.

Comment: So it's too slow in IE even with it only running on enter input. It looks buggy. Big suprise IE :-P. For now I'll have it just run on a timeout for when the stop typing.