# Trigger textarea undo buffer update in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like the textarea undo stack to be updated more often. I read a trick here [Trigger textarea ctrl-z undo buffer update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715261/trigger-textarea-ctrl-z-undo-buffer-update), which works great on Chrome and IE:

Do a blur(); focus(); whenever you want to add to the undo stack.

This, however, does not work on Firefox. Any clever tricks out there? I'm hoping that I won't have create my own undo/redo function and stack.

For those who want to use this trick: it doesn't work on mobile devices. It does add to the undo stack, but the keyboard disappears on blur(). That would be an issue for a different question.

This adds to the undo stack on enter and period in Chrome and IE:

```
$(".textarea").keyup( function() {
      var the_event = arguments[0] || window.event; 
      var key = the_event.keyCode || the_event.charCode;
      if(key == 13 || key == 190){ // enter or period
            $(this).blur(); // saves to undo/redo stack
            $(this).focus();
       }
});
```

Firefox is capturing the event. I checked in the debugger and it does do the blur() and focus()  upon enter.